# My Replt Discord Bot Code is giving me a Weird Error

Tags: python, discord.py

Yesterday, the bot was working fine. I didn't change anything since I last ran the code, but I'm getting a very odd error. And I don't have the skillset to decipher what the error means. If it helps, when I logged onto Replt today, it said that the code was running. I found that weird because it shouldn't have been running while my PC was off, but it could have been a visual bug.

```py
    import os
    import discord
    import random
    import time
    #import keep_alive
    from tarot import *
    #950548917911695433

    player = discord.Client()

    Prefixee = ["hey soupy, ", "is!"]
    #Secrets
    token = os.environ['token']
    #--

    #Run
    #keep_alive.keep_alive()
    #--
    @player.event
    async def on_ready():
      print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(player))



    @player.event
    async def on_message(msge):
     # if msge.channel.name == "log":
      #  await msge.delete()
      cont = msge.content
      guild = msge.guild
      channels = guild.channels
      Prefix = "is!"
      for i in range(len(Prefixee)):
        if cont.startswith(Prefixee[i]):
          Prefix = Prefixee[i]
      if msge.author != player.user:

        if cont.startswith(Prefix+"sayd:"):
          msg = cont[len(Prefix+"sayd:"):(len(cont)+1)].split(":|: ")
          if msge.author.id == 326078895436726282:
            for i in range(len(channels)):
              if channels[i].name == msg[1]:
                await channels[i].send(msg[0])
            
            await msge.delete()
              
        if cont.startswith(Prefix+"say "):
          msg = cont[len(Prefix+"say "):(len(cont)+1)]
          await msge.channel.send("**" + msge.author.name + "** says: \"" + msg + "\"")
        elif (cont.startswith(Prefix+"roles") or cont.startswith(Prefix+"what are the roles")):
          roles = guild.roles
          rolestring = ""
          for i in range(1,len(roles)):
             rolestring = rolestring + "__" + roles[i].name + "__" + " **|** "
          await msge.channel.send(rolestring)
        elif cont.startswith(Prefix+"who are you"):
          whoami = "Hi, " + msge.author.name + """! I'm Soupy! I work for Inauthentic Soup. 
    https://imgur.com/JDwQQGN"""
        elif cont.startswith(Prefix+"tarot"):
          Deck = []
          for i in range(len(tarot)):
            Deck.append(tarot[i])
          random.seed()
          randomCard = random.randrange(0,len(tarot))
          await msge.channel.send("Waring: Online cards are not as effective as real cards.")
          time.sleep(2)
          await msge.channel.send("Shuffling. . . ")
          time.sleep(1)
          await msge.channel.send("You drew " + tarot[randomCard])

        elif cont.startswith("Thank you, Soupy"):
          await msge.channel.send("Happy to help! :D")
        elif cont.startswith("Terminate"):
          await msge.channel.send("Happy to help! :D")
         
    player.run(token)
```

This is my python code. ^^

And my error/output is below.

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
        player.run(token)
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
        return future.result()
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
        await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
        await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
        await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
        data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
      File "/home/runner/ISDungeons/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
        raise HTTPException(r, data)
    discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0)
```

Comment: Either you or someone else on the repl.it server has sent too many requests to Discord. Their API is rate-limited, so you just have to wait some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Replit uses a shared IP, which means the others users who host their bots on replit use the same IP. Many requests from the same IP will result in it getting ratelimited by Discord API. The conclusion is very simple - don't host bots on replit.

Use a VPS instead. There are some options that give you free start credits. For example: https://try.digitalocean.com/freetrialoffer

Comment: A much simpler, always-free solution would be to use google compute engine.